# Azure IoT-Hub Device Key(Shared Access Key) expiry

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

When creating a device in DeviceIdentityRegistry in Azure IoTHub, we get Shared Access Key(DeviceKey) for the device to connect to IotHub, does this Shared Access Key(DeviceKey) expire? If so how long do they live before expiry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Shared Access Key(DeviceKey) won't expire but SAS(Shared Access Signatures) will. You can [update DeviceKeys](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/tools/DeviceExplorer/doc/how_to_use_device_explorer.md#update-device).

Comment: Thank you so much.